# Cannot change port 25 to port 587

Tags: windows-server-2003

I am using outlook 2003. My email provider is Cox. Trying to change my out going port to 587 so I send mail while traveling.  Others I know on Cox have done this with succes, but they are using newer version of outlook.

When I go to change my existing email accounts, outlook will not allow me to change the settings. I can delete 25, but it will not allow me to type in 587.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Tools -> Accounts**.  Select "Change existing mail account".  Click **Next**.  Highlight the account in question, click **Change**.
Click the **More Settings** button.  Go to the last tab marked **Advanced**  Change the Outgoing Server (SMTP) to 587.  Click **OK**.  Click **Next**.  Click **Finish**.  Click **Close**